# How to scroll vertically in appium for hybrid app using java

Tags: java, webview, appium

I am automating a hybrid app and I want scroll vertically from top to bottom in a page which is in web view. I am using java client-5.0.4 and appium version is v1.7.2

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1dRxS.png)

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Yes I tried TouchAction and JavascriptExecutor but no luck

Comment: You need to show the attempts right?

Comment: Actually I tried two methods                                                                          
 1. TouchAction myAction = new TouchAction(driver);
myAction.press(1, 0).moveTo(1, 0).release().perform();                           
2. JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
HashMap scrollObject = new HashMap();
scrollObject.put("direction", "down");
js.executeScript("mobile: scroll", scrollObject);  and I am using java-client 5.0.4, appium server 1.7.2, selenium 3.9.1 and commons-lang3-3.7.jar .

Comment: The problem is code is not throwing any error but scrolling is not happening in the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can swipe in an app with appium using the `press` method. E.g. :

```
TouchAction().press(el0).moveTo(el1).release()
```

It also works with coordinates if you wish to use that instead of webelements.

More information on touch actions can be found here : https://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/touch-actions/

Comment: TouchAction myAction = new TouchAction(driver);
  myAction.tap(ele1).moveTo(ele2).release().perform(); I tried this code but I got Null Pointer exception because ele2 is not visible in the screen as it is located at the bottom position. Kindly help me to resolve this.